# Understanding User Input Behind the Scenes?

Tags: input, game-loop, hardware, operating-system

I am a bit confused on how user input is actually received and processed behind the scenes in a game engine.  Let's say I have a simplistic game loop as follows...

```
while (true)
{
  processInput();
  updateEntities();
  renderGameWorld();
}
```

1. How is the engine able to access input in the processInput() function (for example a key press), if the key is both pressed and released very quickly while the program is executing a different function.  By the time processInput() executes on the next cycle, it seems to me like the program would be "unaware" that this input ever happened.
2. Just from intuition (and I could be very wrong here), I'm guessing that things like keyboard input force a hardware interrupt, store the key value into some kind of device specific storage buffer queue, and then can be accessed and flushed at the correct time (next processInput() call) by a program?
3. If this is true, how does the engine handle stuff like multiple key presses.  If I had a buffer queue that looked something like...

```
----> dequeue (front) [W, W, W, W ,W, Space, C] enqueue (back) <-------
```

If...

- "W" moves my player avatar forward
- "Space" is jump
- "C" is swing sword

Clearly my engine wouldn't care about the identical "W"'s, so would it just flush those until it reached the next unique input? Furthermore, can the engine even check more than one input in the queue per cycle of the game loop (most examples I've seen of processInput() use either a bunch of conditionals or a switch statement to check for a single input variable)? Any insight into this stuff is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the input handling APIs for a few game engines to get an idea of what information they expose? This gives you some good clues about how they're handling the input behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

> How is the engine able to access input in the processInput() function (for example a key press), if the key is both pressed and released very quickly while the program is executing a different function. By the time processInput() executes on the next cycle, it seems to me like the program would be "unaware" that this input ever happened.

This is assuming the user is able to press a button and release it in 1/30 of a second, which is quite fast, but it is still a valid point. What some games have done before to solve this, is add all input in a queue, and when the game reaches the part where it handles input, it handles all input in the queue.

This is why when some games start to lag, you suddenly see all your input be activated at the same time. Although not every game does it this way.

> Just from intuition (and I could be very wrong here), I'm guessing that things like keyboard input force a hardware interrupt, store the key value into some kind of device specific storage buffer queue, and then can be accessed and flushed at the correct time (next processInput() call) by a program?

This is mostly done in the framework/library you'd be using, as far as I'm aware it's not done in the hardware. A lot of frameworks/libraries also give you the power to implement this yourself, that way you have more control over how it works.

> If this is true, how does the engine handle stuff like multiple key presses. If I had a buffer queue that looked something like...

Usually when creating a queue of input, on top of storing which key was triggered, you also record its state. For example your queue can look something like `[{'W', "pressed"}, {'C', "presssed"}]`, this would tell you that on that frame, the `W` key was pressed (the character has to start moving until `W` is released) and the `C` key was pressed (the character attacks).

On a future frame you might receive something like `[{'W', "released"}]`, which is your signal to make the character stop walking.

If you do it this way, you only have to record when a key is pressed, and when it's released, and in between just assumed that the key is being held.

Answer (score 0):

> How is the engine able to access input in the processInput() function (for example a key press), if the key is both pressed and
> released very quickly while the program is executing a different
> function. By the time processInput() executes on the next cycle, it
> seems to me like the program would be "unaware" that this input ever
> happened.

Back in the day, like on Commodore C>64s or the TRS-80, the keyboard was a bunch of memory-mapped switches and to get keypresses without going through the operating system you had to grab that memory and figure out which keys were currently pressed.

On PCs, however, the keyboard is an actual I/O device.  You press a key, the keyboard hardware debounces it, and queues up a "make" message.  You release the key and the keyboard queues up a "break" message.  Neither the operating system nor the processor is involved with detecting physical key presses or releases, and there isn't really any way that you could possibly hit and release a key so quickly that the device misses it.

> Just from intuition (and I could be very wrong here), I'm guessing that things like keyboard input force a hardware interrupt, store the
> key value into some kind of device specific storage buffer queue, and
> then can be accessed and flushed at the correct time (next
> processInput() call) by a program?

The quick answer is that modern USB and Bluetooth keyboards are polled, and the keyboard driver handles the message packets from the keyboard which are then made available to the operating system.  Your programming language generally translates the keyboard data and puts it into a queue for easy "get next key" type usage, but you can bypass your programming language's `input()`, `inkey()`, `readkey()`, or `get_char()` statements and, instead, go through the operating system to interact with the driver more directly in order to get raw, or at least less-cooked, information.

> If this is true, how does the engine handle stuff like multiple key presses. If I had a buffer queue that looked something like...

I'm extemporizing a bit here, but the engine will get the make and break codes from the operating system's keyboard driver and will make a map of keys so that you can query the engine in the form of something like `key.ispressed(KEYW + KEYSPACE + KEYC)` to determine whether a particular key combination is currently being held down.

You indicated that your program would get a string of `w`s, for example, because the `w` key is being held down, but this isn't how it would work.  If the engine were using a call like getkey() or something like that then yes, you'd get a buffered string of repeated `w`s when that key is held down, but that's why the engine wouldn't do it that way.  The engine would get the raw make and break codes and manage the keyboard map itself.

DMGregory's suggestion to take a look at the keyboard functions from a few game engine APIs is a good one.